# Strategy for Laravel scout with million+ records and multiple interchangeable drivers (i.e. TNT & Algolia)

Tags: laravel, search, full-text-search, algolia, laravel-scout

I have used Algolia a bit and it is an awesome service. I have also used the TNT-search driver for scout and it is also pretty good, but not really a touch on the features, speed and ease that you get with Algolia.

Unfortunately, Algolia gets very expensive when dealing with a lot of records - for example one of our apps has over 10 million searchable rows, which would be thousands of $$ monthly!

Has anyone had any success in using both together? i.e. I would like use Algolia for recent records or categories where I need more advanced search capabilities (100k of records) and then use TNT search for the remainder.

EDIT:

Elasticsearch was the answer. It is a little harder to setup but has such great flexibility. I would highly recommend https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch to connect it up with Laravel Scout seamlessly.

Comment: You can try my elasticsearch driver for scout https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ,**AWS Elasticsearch** very good and cheap .. you might use it and it's very easy to use and configure with laravel [AWS Elasticsearch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3)
You may start with **r3.large.elasticsearch** it will costs you about 180$ per month and if you want to more **r3.xlarge.elasticsearch**     will be amazing too and it will serve you need.

to configure AWS Elasticsearch with laravel you may read this artical [How-to integrate-your-Laravel-app-with-Elasticsearch](https://madewithlove.be/how-to-integrate-your-laravel-app-with-elasticsearch/)

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch is already suggested in another answer as a cost effective alternative. But if you are looking for something similar to Algolia but open source, check out [Typesense](https://github.com/typesense/typesense). It's must easier to set-up and manage and also features like typo correction etc. just works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late but if there is anyone who still has this problem, Laravel scout has a `searchableUsing()` method that determines the search engine to use, you can override that to configure different search drivers for different models. [This blogpost is a detailed step by step on how to do this](https://medium.com/@fzahra/laravel-how-to-configure-multiple-search-providers-30e205776f60)